# Up to date overview of experimental approaches to quantum computing

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization

I'm interested in getting an overview of the leading approaches to quantum computing from a physics perspective. I've read most of Nielsen and Chuang, but its chapter on physical realizations looks extremely out of date.

Is there a resource at a similar level that covers the approaches used by, e.g. Google, Microsoft, Pan's group, and IBM? I've seen a lot of qualitative material, but it's usually aimed at computer science people and thus physics-free. I'm looking for something at the level of "here's the Hamiltonian describing a single qubit, here's the interaction Hamiltonian describing a gate, here's how readout is done", and so on.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interesting in superconducting qubit architecture then these might be helpful:

[Superconducting Qubits:Current State of Play](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.13641.pdf)

[A Quantum Engineer’s Guide to Superconducting Qubits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06560.pdf)

The other things you can do is probably follow people in the field that working on these technologies and read their publications. For example, you can follow [John Martinis's group](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/index.shtml) and go over their publications, presentations, etc. The other things that might be very helpful is to go through his students [PhD dissertations](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses.shtml) which is where you probably find the most details work.

For trapped-ion system, you can follow [Chris Monroe's group](http://iontrap.umd.edu/publications/). Again, he put up all of his [past student's dissertations](http://iontrap.umd.edu/publications/theses/) on his website so you can go through them as well.

Comment: Regarding John Martinis' group: these links are still useful (especially PhD dissertations), but for most up-to-date information, I'd also include the link to the new website: https://quantumai.google/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would highly recommend Appendix B, C and D of this book written by the National Academy of Sciences: https://www.nap.edu/catalog/25196/quantum-computing-progress-and-prospects (you can click on Download Free PDF for an electronic copy). Even though it is about 3 years old, I don't believe there have been huge advancements in terms of the fundamentals since then. I actually would recommend reading the whole thing :)